# App causes phone to restart and bypass pin? Possible cause?

Tags: android

So I launched Beta test on my app and one of the testers has reported that app causes phone to reboot and bypass PIN.

However there are some key points to this:
*App does not restart or launch after phone is rebooted.
*Apps permissions are:
**Storage
**Location
**Internet Access
**Disable key lock (to awake screen when conditions are met)
**View Network Status
**Control Vibrator
**Access Accounts
**Set alarms.

Also:
*The only phone that has this problem is Samsung S5, other's seem fine.
*App was tested on 2.3 Android as well (minimum required version) and worked fine.
*App was tested on latest Android versions including 4.4

I have suspicion it's the hardware fault of the tester but looking for suggestions as to possible causes?

The tester with S5 had submitted crash report and it shows as this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:820)
at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:348)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:139)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:112)
at als.wakeup.Awake_Alarm$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Awake_Alarm.java:272)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It points to my Notifications but they work fine on all phones except that testers S5.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: well I guess if the issue is device-specific you will need to get an S5 and make some proper debugging. If you still won't be able to find the reason for the problem, consider contacting Samsung about the issue

Comment: Has the S5 had a custom ROM installed on it?

Comment: No custom ROM, standard.